# Text in vertical middle of Div

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

How can I align text in the vertical middle of a `Div` element provided it has a `position:absolute` property specified?

Setting `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the text contained within any element other element, a `p`, `span`, `div` or similar? Can you post the precise html of the relevant section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap an inner div and give it `position:relative; top:-50%;` in addition to giving the absolute a `top:50%`.

Though of course if it's complicated styling, please provide your CSS.

You can get away with `line-height` if it's just a single line of text, you'd have to kill the `absolute` rule though.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. My code is as follows:

body > div (absolute positioning with margin:0 auto; for centering > div with position absolute (repeating element) > other tags + the div I want to have vertically centered text in. It also has absolute positioning.

It has an unknown number of lines of text. It has top:0 and bottom:0 so that it is as high as it's parent div.

Looks complicated... sorry.