# vertical alignment of image inside a div

Tags: css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I want to set vertical alignment of image inside a div. I use img { vertical-align:middle}
but it is not working.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535689/text-in-vertical-middle-of-div.

Comment: As a newbie, you might want to up-vote some of these answers since they are pointing you in the right direction and we are all taking time out of work/life to help each other.

Answer (score 16):

Using the `line-height` property will solve the problem:

```
<style> 
.someclass {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  border: dotted;
}
.someclass img {
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<div class="someclass"> 
  <img src="someimg.jpg" border="0" alt=""> 
</div>
```

Comment: for ie you may have to introduce zoom

Comment: In contrast to display table-cell, this works like a charm down to IE7. Thanks!

Comment: table-cell made height:100% stop working in my case.

Answer (score 7):

This is a solution that doesn't require JavaScript (as my previous solution did).

You can achieve what you want by assigning `display: table-cell` to the containing div. Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/evuqo5/2/edit

I feel I must warn you that you will need to test this in every browser you intend to support. Support for the `table-cell` value is fairly new, particularly in Firefox. I know it works in Firefox 4, but I don't know about any of the 3.x iterations. You'll also want to test in IE (I've only tested in Chrome 10 and Firefox 4).

The CSS:

```
  div#container {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;  
  }
  div#container img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
```

You won't need the `div#container img` styles if you don't also want to horizontally align the image.

Comment: This will not work if you need to use a percentage for the height, as it was my case.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do what I think, vertical align isn't going to work; you'll need to use positioning.

In general, position the container relative, and then position the image absolute, with top and left set to 50%, and then move the image back to the center by setting negative margins equal to half the width / height.

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/evuqo5/edit

Basic CSS is this:

```
#container { position: relative; }
#container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: /* -1/2 the height of the image */
  margin-left: /* -1/2 the width of the image */
}
```

Comment: i dont want to calculate height and width of every image

Comment: I'll post another solution that will work without JavaScript, but may not be supported in every browser.

Comment: I do not know the image's dimensions. It has width set to a percentage, and height is left unset, so that it scales proportionally.

Answer (score 2):

See this awser: [How to vertical align image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336503/how-to-vertical-align-image-inside-div#answer-11716065)

If you want to align horizontally also, add the `right` and `left`, like this:

```
div {
  position:relative;
}
img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the div `display` attribute to `table-cell` then `vertical-align: middle;` will work.

The `vertical-align` rule only affects table cells or elements with `display: table-cell`.

See [this article from SitePoint](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/) for a detailed explanation.

```
<style>
/* change body to .someClasses's parent */

body {
  width: 100%;
  height:  100%;
  display: table;
}
body > .someclass {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    border:dotted;
    margin: 0 auto
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="someclass"> 
        <img src="someimg.jpg" border="0" alt=""> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you're right I missed something. I've updated the code to work. If you had actually bothered to take the time to read the link I posted you'd have noticed this for yourself and fixed this problem already. Please make an effort to actually learn something rather simply asking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

The following post has some useful references:

[Text Alignment w/ IE9 in Standards-Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424294/text-alignment-w-ie9-in-standards-mode)

Also, depending on which version of IE you are testing against, you may end up needing some browser-specific hacks or some jQuery/JavaScript code.

If you have to, use a one-row-one-cell table and take advantage of the `vertical-align` property.  This is brute-force, not overly semantic, but it works.