# Image in a DIV - vertical centered

Tags: css, image, html

i have a DIV with a size x and some images in it with often a larger size. And in this case i need the image vertical centered in this DIV.

Dows anyone know, how i can realize that?

Thanks for reading that!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336503/how-to-vertical-align-image-inside-div

Comment: To make your question clearer, can you [show what you have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I have it: display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;

Comment: display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle doesn't work in older browsers (IE7)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the images inside divs and place those divs into the Your div and after words to center them

You can also make a class fo those divs and in the css part position:center;

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertical alignment as here http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If the div contains only images and no text/one liner, you can set line-height=height and use vertical-align to center the image.

```
<div style="height: 10px; line-height: 10px">
    <img src="" style="vertical-align: middle"/> 
</div>
```

PS: It is important to have a space character after the `<img/>` to force the image to align to the space in IE6.