# My jQuery IMG center script fails in Chrome and Safari, but works IE?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an e-commerce site where I'm displaying all my products and the thumbnails need to be centered in a div. The centering works in IE(even in compatibility mode), FF, and Opera, but fails in Chrome and Safari. In Chrome and Safari the image stays on the top of the div and does not center. I've changed my CSS around trying to locate the problem, but I can't seem to find what's causing the issue? Anyone see anything?

**IE (GOOD)**

[image]

**CHROME (BAD)**

[image]

**JQUERY**

```
var _h = $('div.product-image').height();
$('div.product-image img').each(function()
{
    var _top = (_h - $(this).height()) / 2;
    $(this).css('margin-top',_top);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.product
{
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.product-image
{
    margin:2px auto;
    width:194px;
    height:145px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.product-image img
{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border:1pc solid #999;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-model">sadf</div>
            <div class="product-price"> : 234</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="2.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-model">sdaf</div>
            <div class="product-bottom"> : 2345</div>
        </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

Here's the Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/anaZD/

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for this? Look in to vertical-align(might need to play around with line-height too). http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: Any chance of a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: That was my direction at first, but it seemed to not work in IE. All the images are different heights. The first image aligned prefectly, but all the others did not. I'll try again since I need to get this working today .. pressure's on ;)

Comment: @ David, I'll try to put something together. I need to find images around the same size ... stand by ...

Comment: Why the down vote? I asked a legit question?

Comment: Hm, looking at the down votes this is not a legit question. Sorry guys!

Comment: Having looked at your JS Fiddle it worked for me (Chromium 22/Ubuntu 12.10) as soon as jQuery was selected from the library drop-down on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/anaZD/1/ Incidentally, [the `each()` is unnecessary](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/anaZD/2/).

Comment: Hm, it works on JS Fiddle, but not off my XAMPP? I added the .each() so it would evaluate every image on the page, rather than the first. I'll try it without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check this, it worked for me:

[How to vertical align image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336503/how-to-vertical-align-image-inside-div/11716065#11716065)

```
div {position:relative;}
    img {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;}
    .image {min-height:50px}
```

div is your .product-image
img is .product-image img

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is with margintop. jQuery CSS uses 'marginTop' rather than 'margin-top' and you might want those images instead to be positioned relatively based on your calculations on the original script.

Here is an example, can you clarify if that's what you are trying to accomplish? See attached the JsFiddle

The Javacript

```
   var a=$;
   a.noConflict();

   var CountP=new Array();

    jQuery(function(a){

    a("div.product-image img").each(function(b,c){

    CountP[c]=(( a(this).parent('div').parent('div').height() -  a(this).height() )  / 2) +'px';
```

//Alert as we go for testing

```
alert('The difference that we are looking for this product is: ' + CountP[c] + ' and the height of this product is:' + a(this).height() );
```

To ensure browser compatibility try with marginTop for CSS or like in this example, 
position:relative; top and left values;

```
   a(this).css({'border':'2px inset red','position':'relative',
'top': CountP[c], 'left':'0.1em','margin':'auto','marginTop':'0.1px', 'display':'inline-block'});

})



});
```

Below a test on jsfiddle.net.. hope it help you out!
http://jsfiddle.net/mt5fk/93/

Answer (score 0):

With your provided images ;) The JS is the same but it does not allow me to update with the link

```
 var a=$;
 a.noConflict();

var CountP=new Array();

 jQuery(function(a){
a("div.product-image img").each(function(b,c){

    CountP[c]=(( a(this).parent('div').parent('div').height() -  a(this).height() )  / 2) +'px';


    alert('The difference that we are looking for this product is: ' + CountP[c] + ' and the height of this product is:' + a(this).height() );


    //to ensure browser compatibility try with marginTop for CSS or like in this example, position:relative; top and left values;
    a(this).css({'border':'2px inset red','position':'relative','top': CountP[c], 'left':'0.1em','margin':'auto','marginTop':'0.1px', 'display':'inline-block'});



    });

 });
```

New JSFiddle

```
    http://jsfiddle.net/mt5fk/94/
```