# Vertical aligning an img element within a div

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to vertical align my ing element within a div. Only problem is the img element doesn't have a fixed height. I tried vertical-align in combination with table, table-cell and inline-block and inline. None of this seems to work. Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? I made a JSFiddle that recreates my problem.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gMcK/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="image-container">
    <img src="http://www.image2012.com/images/2013/03/landscapes-landscape-free.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image-container {
    padding:5px;
    height: 135px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table;
    float:left;
}

#image-container img{
    display: table-cell;
    max-height:125px;

    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Read here how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336503/how-to-vertical-align-image-inside-div - Also I updated your fiddle to your specs http://jsfiddle.net/6gMcK/2/

Comment: @limelights I think this should be an answer...

Comment: @MarcelGwerder No, I believe this should've been dug out before asking the question since everything else is just a copy of it. I don't believe in duplicate or copying answers.

Comment: @limelights Of course but it's still a working sollution.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. This doesn't work on a floated parent though. I nested my img in another container that isn't floated. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @FrankKluytmans exactly, thats why i removed float:left from your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Change some properties **as like this**

```
   #image-container {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 135px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#image-container img{
    max-height: 125px;
    display: block;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/6gMcK/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

A solution I often use is to have the image be the background of the image container. This way I can set the width and height to whatever it needs to be and for any image and size of the container, with a little absolute positioning and the full image is always displayed.

```
#image-container {
    position:absolute;
    left:30%;
    right:30%;
    min-width:135px;
    height: 135px;

    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image:url('image.png');
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Of course you can always play around with the values for the width depending on what your needs are. I always found this to be a simple solution for displaying images.

Comment: Please note: These are CSS3 properties, so this solution will work on modern browsers, but not on IE<9.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have one image in the container , and the container has a fixed height, then you could simply apply `line-height = container_height_px` to the container

Try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GxLHa/1/)**

Comment: If we reduce the img-container height to 100px, we can see the image is not exactly vertically centered (which may be annoying in some cases), cause it still has default display: inline. Best cross-browser solution for vertical centering is to use old table and give the img display: block. It would work on 20th century browsers too.

Comment: The question didn't say that the container had a variable height, it said the the **img** had a variable height