# Vertical align img in DIV

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical align an IMG in a DIV but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.
It works in FF and IE7, but other browsers just align it to the top.
Code can be found here:

http://disgeae.nl/testomgeving/

Comment: Check this link i use it and its usefull for you [vertical align image in div][1]


 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336503/how-to-vertical-align-image-inside-div/11716065#11716065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
  .wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
  }

  .wraptocenter * {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>.wraptocenter span {    display: inline-block;    height: 100%;}/style>
<![endif]-->

<div class="wraptocenter"><span></span><img src="..." alt="..."></div>
```

Check this out [link](http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html) out, it has certainly helped me out:

Comment: link only answers are bad practice, you should add some description to it.