# How to fit image in div tag

Tags: asp.net

i have image inside div tag. when i change image (with high resolution)
 url from code behind , it shows scrolling for that div. How to fit image to div.

Here is my code

```
 <div class="imageCols">
    <img runat="server" id="imgOriginal" alt="orgImg" />
 </div>
```

imgOriginal.Src = "ProfilePictures/" + Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();

Comment: You can specify the height and width with css, but the full image is still being downloaded so if possible you might want to consider resizing the actual image.

Comment: A possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336503/how-to-vertical-align-image-inside-div/11716065#11716065

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
.imageCols img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.imageCols
{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

Works in all modern browsers